# Auto Adjust Storyboard Webview size according to navigation bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, ios6, storyboard

I have a webview in a viewcontroller with a navigation bar and a toolbar. I have a hide toolbar and nav bar button, but when they hide the size of the webview doesn't adjust to fit the screen. I used this code:

```
-(IBAction)hide:(id)sender {
myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
[[[self navigationController] navigationBar]  setHidden:YES];
[[[self navigationController] toolbar] setHidden:YES];
   [self.view addSubview:myView];
 }

 -(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {

return YES;

 }

 -(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {

    myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,382);
    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar]  setHidden:NO];
    [[[self navigationController] toolbar] setHidden:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

}

 }
```

They hide properly but how can i adjust the size properly? Im using storyboard btw.

Answer (score 1):

What is myView?

Try setting the following on the instance of the UIViewView in `-(void)viewDidLoad` or via Interface Builder/Storyboard:

```
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

By setting the autoresizing mask as shown, when the view's superview changes its bounds the webview will grow and shrink with it.

Comment: myView is the webView, I placed the code in the view did load but it still doesn't work, whats wrong?